# Comprobar checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Buenas, he puesto un pequeño cuestionario y al final tengo un checkbox para aceptar el tema de las políticas de privacidad. Pero no consigo comprobar si lo han seleccionado o no.

**Me gustaría que saliese un alert cuando NO ha sido seleccionado**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var estructuraMail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$/;

  $('#Btn-Contacto-Enviar').click(function() {

    var nombre = $('#Nombre').val();
    var apellidos = $('#Apellidos').val();
    var mail = $('#Mail').val();
    var telefono = $('#Telefono').val();
    var comentario = $('#Comentario').val();

    var checkLOPD = $("#Checkbox-lopd:checked");

    if (nombre == "") {
      alert("El campo nombre es obligatorio");
    } else {
      if (apellidos == "") {
        alert("El campo apellidos es obligatorio");
      } else {
        if (mail == "") {
          alert("El campo e-Mail es obligatorio");
        } else {
          if (!estructuraMail.test(mail)) {
            alert("El correo electrónico no es válido");
          } else {
            if (telefono == "") {
              alert("El campo teléfono es obligatorio");
            } else {
              if (isNaN(telefono)) {
                alert("El numero de teléfono ha de ser numérico");
              } else {
                if (comentario == "") {
                  alert("¡Cuéntame algo!");
                } else {
                  if( $('#Checkbox-lopd').is(':checked') ) {
                    alert('Seleccionado');
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 4):

Como veo que utilizas **JQuery** tambien puedes intentar :

```
$('#Checkbox-lopd').is(':checked')
```

o  tal vez

```
$('#Checkbox-lopd').attr('checked')
```

ambos metodos devuelven un `boolean` (`true` o `false`) como respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar se encuentra disponible de la version 1.6 en adelante de jquery

```
if( $('.micheckbox').prop('checked') ) {
alert('Seleccionado');
```

}

o desde versiones anteriores:

```
if( $('.micheckbox').attr('checked') ) {
alert('Seleccionado');
```

}

te dejo mas informacion acerca de esto: https://cybmeta.com/comprobar-sin-un-checkbox-esta-seleccionado-con-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Te vasta con utilizar:

```
if( $('#Checkbox-lopd').is(':checked') ) {
    alert('Seleccionado');
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias he editado la pregunta usando tu respuesta. Porque me decían que era un duplicado y a mi me interesa cuando no ha sido marcado. Saludos